# Fetching new Gmail emails after a timestamp

Tags: go, gmail, gmail-api

I am going through Gmail API docs(https://developers.google.com/gmail/api), I am able to read all the user emails which are present in the inbox.

eg snippet (reading complete list of emails):

```golang
for {
        req := svc.Users.Messages.List("me")
        r, _ := req.Do()
        for _, m := range r.Messages {
            msg, _ := svc.Users.Messages.Get("me", m.Id).Do()
            date := ""
            for _, h := range msg.Payload.Headers {
                if h.Name == "Date" {
                    date = h.Value
                    break
                }
            }
            msgs = append(msgs, message{
                ...
            })
        }
    }
```

Now, when new emails come I want to read them as well (either immediately or after some time). I can write a scheduled job for that purpose, But I am not sure if I can fetch email after a particular timestamp or after an email identifier. I don't want to read a whole bunch of emails, again and again, to figure out the new emails, in this way, there is a lot of unnecessary computation being involved. Is there any way I can make this task easier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Looking at the docs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list), it looks like it supports a query parameter, `q`.

The query parameter supports the same options as available in the Gmail search bar:

> Only return messages matching the specified query. Supports the same query format as the Gmail search box. For example, "from:someuser@example.com rfc822msgid:somemsgid@example.com is:unread". Parameter cannot be used when accessing the api using the gmail.metadata scope.

This means you can do something like `"after:YYYY/MM/DD"` or with a timestamp `"after:1616819452"`.

```golang
req := svc.Users.Messages.List("me").Q("after:2021/01/01")
```

See the full usage here https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/gmail/v1#UsersMessagesListCall.Q

Comment: thanks, That one I already looked at, but the query is on date, I was looking to query after timestamp

Comment: @AmitUpadhyay it also supports timestamps. See updated answer.